# multiple application of mapply

Tags: r, functional-programming, apply

Is there a higher order version of `mapply`, such that it will iterate across a list and find the difference between each of the sub-components?

I have a list `LL` which contains sub-lists, and I want to find the differences between each of the sub-lists. If I did it separately, I would do the following.

```
mapply("-", LL[[1]], LL[[2]])
mapply("-", LL[[1]], LL[[3]])
mapply("-", LL[[2]], LL[[3]])
```

At present I am using the below approach -- but it feels like a hack (it's not very *functional*).

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = 1:5
x2 = 5:1
x3 = seq(2, 10, 2)
xl <- list(x1, x2, x3)
y1 = rnorm(5)
y2 = runif(5)
y3 = seq(20, 12, -2)
yl <- list(y1, y2, y3)
z1 = rnorm(5)
z2 = runif(5)
z3 = seq(20, 12, -2) %% 3
zl <- list(z1, z2, z3)
LL <- list(xl, yl, zl)

LLdiff <- list()
combs <- combn(1:length(LL), 2)
for (i in 1:ncol(combs)) {
    LLdiff[[i]] <- mapply("-", LL[[combs[,i][1]]], LL[[combs[,i][2]]])
}
```

What's the `R` / `functional` way of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach. `combn` has `FUN` to allow using functions inside, so combining `combn` and `mapply` will give you the answer (just one alternative :D)

```
combn(1:length(LL), 2, function(x)  mapply("-", LL[[x [1]]], LL[[x [2]]]), FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to store these as matrices rather than list of lists. Try this:

```
# Convert to matrices.
new.LL<-lapply(seq_along(LL),function(f)do.call(cbind,LL[[f]]))
# Loop over each combo
lapply(apply(combn(1:length(new.LL),2),2,
  function(x) new.LL[x]),function(x) x[[1]]-x[[2]])
```

Another, somewhat more appealing strategy:

```
combos<-combn(1:length(new.LL),2)
mapply(`-`, new.LL[combos[1,]],new.LL[combos[2,]],SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Perhaps consider `sweep`?